# How to deal with IE's not encoding URL in django?

Tags: django, internet-explorer, get, url-encoding

In browsers like chrome and firefox, if you type something like this into the address line:

```
http://mysite.com/q?name=喇叭嘴
```

they help you encode the url into:

```
http://mysite.com/?q=%E5%96%87%E5%8F%AD%E5%98%B4
```

So, in django, you can just use:

```
request.GET.get('q', '')
```

to get the value `'喇叭嘴'`.

However, this thing does not happen in IE(msie, thanks). That's why we keep on getting `���` instead.

With ajax handling, I can just use JavaScript `encodeURI()` Function to work around with it. However, triggering it every time is such a pain.

Is there any way to handle the issue in the backend?

Comment: ref http://ued.taobao.com/blog/2011/08/26/encode-war/ and http://www.ruanyifeng.com/blog/2010/02/url_encoding.html . (Both in Chinese.)

Comment: Do you want to convert it as an answer? I will accept it if it's the best one :)

Comment: I've no idea how do you get the value of the `q` in client side, thus post those helpful links in case you could solve it.(maybe post more code?)  =)